# The code to turn off the rgb led by pressing the 4, 5, 6 switches in sequence doesn't work

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm making photoresister alarm. When distance under 5cm over notes[] 5 times, piezo speaker off.  And I want to turn off the led rgb by pressing the 4, 5, 6 switches in sequence.
The code to turn off the led rgb by pressing the 4, 5, 6 switches in sequence does not work.
What's wrong?
Here is a code below.

```
int pins[]={4,5,6};
int melody[]={262,294,330};
int notes[]={392,392,440,440,392,392,330};
int b=0,r=0,g=0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   pinMode(pins[i],INPUT);
 }
}
int c=0;
int value1=digitalRead(4);
int value2=digitalRead(5);
int value3=digitalRead(6);

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int vin=analogRead(A0);
  if (c>5){
    //  b=0,r=0,g=0;
    noTone(8);
    //analogWrite(11,b);
    //analogWrite(10,r);
    //analogWrite(9,g);
   // return;
  }
  if(digitalRead(0)==HIGH){ 
    if(digitalRead(1)==HIGH){
      if(digitalRead(2)==HIGH){
       b=0,r=0,g=0;
       noTone(8);
       analogWrite(11,b);
       analogWrite(10,r);
       analogWrite(9,g);
       return;
      }
    }
  }
  if(vin>800){
    for(int i=0; i<7 ;i++){
      tone(8,notes[i],100);
      delay(200);
      noTone(8);
      analogWrite(11,random(256));
      analogWrite(10,random(256));
      analogWrite(9,random(256));
      delay(200);
    }
  }
  long duration = pulseIn(3,HIGH);
  long distance=duration/58.2;
  if(duration == 0){
    return;
  }
  if (distance<5){
    c++;
  }

}
```

The code to turn off the led rgb by pressing the 4, 5, 6 switches in sequence, rgb led is off.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a bit wrong here, but let's just focus on your 4,5,6 sequence. In your loop, you need to be keeping track of whether and what button has been pressed. What you want to use here is a case/switch setup. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/switchcase/

Each time through the loop you'll check if a button is pressed. Then traverse your cases. I would do something like this: (pseudo-code)

```
int state = 0; //0=no buttons, 1=4 pressed, 2=4,5 pressed, 3= 4,5,6 pressed

switch(pressedButton) {
case 4: 
 if(state == 0){
  state = 1;
 } else state = 0; 

case 5:
 if(state == 1) {
  state = 2;
 } else state = 0;

case 6:
 if(state == 2) {
  state = 3;
 } else state = 0;
}
if(state == 3) {
 //turn off LED
 state = 0;
}
```